# Error login with mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to create an application that can authenticate to amazon using mechanize, but after submitting the form always returns error login.

My code is:

```
import mechanize

URL='http://www.amazon.es/gp/flex/sign-out.html'
EMAIL=''
PASS=''
#Creating a browser object
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv( True )
br.set_handle_gzip( True )
br.set_handle_redirect( True ) 
br.set_handle_referer( True )
br.set_handle_robots( False )

br.set_handle_refresh( mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time = 1)
br.addheaders = [ ( 'User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1' ) ]

#Open login page and inspect
response = br.open(URL)

#Select form by name - "signIn"
br.select_form('signIn')
#Login: Fill 'controls' in 'signIn' form
br['email'] = EMAIL
br['password']=PASS
response = br.submit()

# Print the response
print response.geturl()
print response.read()
```

The response always is

> El correo electrónico o la contraseña eran incorrectos. Vuelva a
>   intentarlo.

I have looked at many examples and I can not see that I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to login why are you requesting `http://www.amazon.es/gp/flex/sign-out.html`?

Comment: I'am testing also that redirection works. The url redirect to https://www.amazon.es/gp/sign-in.html